# If the infinite cardinals aleph-null, aleph-two, etc. continue indefinitely, is there any meaning in the idea of aleph-aleph-null?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If the infinite cardinals aleph-null, aleph-two, etc. continue indefinitely, is there any meaning in the idea of aleph-aleph-null?

Apologies if this isn't a sensible question, I really don't know too much about these infinite cardinals aside from the basics. I did, however, think that the idea of the "aleph-null"th aleph number was interesting enough to base my username on and my own attempts did not prove fruitful, so I was wondering if anyone here could shed some light. Thanks!

For clarity: I'm asking about $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ . Thanks!

P.S. I was somewhat unsure about the tags for this, sorry if I accidentally placed it in the wrong category.

Comment: Are you asking about $\aleph_{\aleph _0}$?

Comment: @GitGud yes, I'll put it in that formatting in the body of the question for clarity

Comment: FYI: make sure that your actual question is in the body of your post.  It's confusing to have it only in the title.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd like to elaborate on some of the fine points that Arthur raised.

The $\aleph$ numbers (also the $\beth$ numbers) are used to denote *cardinals*. However one of the key features of cardinals is that we can say "the next cardinal", and we can say which cardinal came first and which came second. These are *ordinal* properties.

Note that the least cardinal greater than $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ also has countably many [infinite] cardinals smaller than itself. But since $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$, what sense would that make?

So we are using the ordinals. It's a fine point, because the finite notions coincide, the finite cardinals are the finite ordinals, and it's not until we reach the infinite ordinals that we run into the difference between $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$.

Therefore, instead of $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ we have $\aleph_\omega$, then we have $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ and so on and so forth. After we have gone through uncountably many of these we finally have $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, where $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal -- which corresponds to $\aleph_1$.

And so on and so forth. For every ordinal $\alpha$ we have $\aleph_\alpha$ is the unique cardinal that the infinite cardinals below it have the same order type as $\alpha$.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, mostly.  It's the least cardinal for which there are infinitely many infinite cardinals below.  And it is usually denoted $\aleph_\omega$. (Where $\omega$ denotes the least infinite *ordinal*; of course, $\omega = \aleph_0$, but we use $\omega$ to indicate that we are interested in *ordinal* properties of this object. Another description for $\aleph_\omega$ is that it is the $\omega$'th infinite cardinal, or the unique cardinal such that the order-type of the family of all infinite cardinals below it is $\omega$.)

Comment: And is the smallest non numerable cardinal with numerable cofinality.

Comment: @Martin: Nonsense. Every limit *ordinal* has countable cofinality.

Comment: @Martín: Are you trying to say that $\aleph_\omega$ is the smallest uncountable cardinal with countable cofinality? If so, while true it doesn't really help explain what the subscript has to do with anything.

Comment: @Asaf, you are the expert here, but for all the *cardinals* $\aleph_n$, $0<n<\omega$: cf$(\aleph_n)=\aleph_n$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, right (numerable=countable, non numerable=uncountable, true?).

Comment: @Martin: I'm just messing with you. :-) It's consistent without the axiom of choice that for every $\alpha$, $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\alpha)=\omega$. :-) I should have put a smiley face at the end of my previous comment...

Comment: @Asaf, I always forgot that you are the non-AC guy here.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, I sometime that these jokes a bit too far. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question has been answered but I would like to provide a way of visualizing $\aleph_\omega$ and $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$:

Start with $\aleph_0$ and consider the sequence $\aleph_0, \aleph_1,... \aleph_n,...$ for $n \in \omega.$

This is a strictly monotone increasing sequence that has a limit, namely $\aleph_\omega$, which would make $\aleph_\omega$ the smallest uncountable limit cardinal. This number does have applications. Example: if GHC holds and $\aleph_\lambda = \beth_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$, then $|V_{\omega +\omega}|=\beth_\omega=\aleph_{\omega}$. In other words $\aleph_\omega$ would be the cardinality of the von Neumann universe $V_{\omega +\omega}$ which is a universe sufficient for most ordinary mathematics, and is a model of Zermelo set theory.

As to $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$, consider the sequence $\aleph_\omega, \aleph_{\omega+1},...,\aleph_{\omega^2},...,\aleph_{\omega^\omega},...,\aleph_{\epsilon_0},...$

Notice that this also is a strictly monotone increasing sequence which is countable, the supremum of which is a $\aleph_{\omega_1}$. Continuing on like this yields $\aleph_{\omega_1}, \aleph_{\omega_2},...,\aleph_{\omega_n},...$ the limit of which is $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, note that $\aleph_1$ can be interpreted as there is one cardinal ($\aleph_0$) smaller than it. In the same way, there are 100 cardinal numbers smaller than $\aleph_{100}$ ($\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \dots, \aleph_{99}$).

The smallest infinite list of cardinals is hence $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ also denoted $\aleph_{\omega}$.

We may even continue with $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$ (the smallest infinite list of the smallest infinite lists of cardinals) and so on.

Comment: I don't understand $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Consider the infinte list starting with $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ with the even larger cardinals $\aleph_{\aleph_1}, \aleph_{\aleph_2}, \aleph_{\aleph_3}, \dots$ all the way up to $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: (1) The indexing is done by ordinals. Not by cardinals, as Arthur pointed out, and I elaborated. (2) I understand what $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$ would be, but I'm unclear as to the remark in the parenthesis.